# How can I change my NAS SSID and wireless password?

Tags: passwords, nas, ssid

I have a Synology DS213 NAS, which appears under my wireless networks as "diskstation". I want to change the SSID and, more importantly, set a password to it. (Currently it has none.)
I can't seem to find where I change these. Do I have to go into DSM (DiskStation Manager)? I can't find my way in the gazillion of options there.

**edit**
K.A says I have to change that in my router, but my network connection to the NAS doesn't go via a router; the NAS itself provides the connection. (The built-in router doesn't seem to provide the necessary options.)

**edit2** (after K.A's answer update)
I already looked into Control Panel | Network, but there doesn't seem to be anything:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Can you show the "Hotspot" pane? That's probably what you're connecting to.

Comment: @K.A - That's it! I thought I had checked each of the 10000 options. Thanks a bunch. If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Added to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options require you to go into the DSM by going to `http://diskstation/` and logging in as `admin`.

For changing the name the NAS uses on the network, go to `Control Panel > System > Network`. The server name field (defaults to `DiskStation`) sounds like what you are after. If you want to change the actual SSID of the network, that has to be done at the wireless access point or router.

As far as setting a password, go to `Control Panel > File Sharing and Privileges > User` and select `admin` and then `Edit`. This will let you change the administrator access password. You can do the same with other user accounts.

**Edit:**

According to the manual, there should be a `Wireless` tab in the `Network` control panel. Check there and if you need help, post a screenshot of it.

Source: http://ukdl.synology.com/download/Document/UserGuide/DSM/4.3/Syno_UsersGuide_NAServer_enu.pdf

**Edit again:**

You should go to `Control Panel > System > Network > Network Interface > Hotspot` and there change the SSID and add password.

Comment: Thanks, but these I already found. I'm a bit afraid that my question has nothing to do with DSM at all ("that has to be done at the wireless access point or router"). Thanks anyway.

Comment: @stevenvh: If you change the SSID at the router or AP, you will lose access to the NAS unless you reset it OR can directly connect to it via Ethernet and reconfigure it that way.